# Node.js convert Buffer to object/function

Tags: javascript, node.js

`fs.readFile()`, `fs.readFileSync()` and also `Amazon S3` return a `Buffer` object. How can I use this Buffer as actual JavaScript code that I can execute?

Here is a very basic example.

*some-file.js:*

```
module.exports = function () {
    console.log('hello');
};
```

*main.js*

```
const data1 = fs.readFileSync('./some-file.js'); // This is a Buffer
const data2 = fs.readFileSync('./some-file.js', 'utf-8'); // This is a string

data1(); // Error: data1 is not a function
JSON.parse(data2)(); // Error: data2 is no valid JSON
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly, what's your expected output?

Comment: I load a file from Amazon S3 that contains JavaScript function (Handlebars template) that I need to execute.

Answer (score 2):

It *sounds* like you are after something like [eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eval) for the function scenario (not the evil version, this one leverages the [vm module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html)). The other option here is to save the contents of the buffer to a file and then let `require` do it's thing (not sure if that's an option for you).

The object scenario is simpler, if `Buffer` is a JSON string then you should simply be able to call `JSON.parse(buffer.toString('utf8'))`

Comment: Seems like `.toString()` and then `eval()` is my only rescue. I was hoping to avoid using `eval()`

Comment: Saving to a file is not an option for me since my code is executed serverless so i dont have a filesystem

Comment: @Mick the `eval` library I've linked too is safer than native `eval`, it leverages Node's [VM module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html), so a lot safer. Alternatively, you can use this module directly, the library just provides a neater interface for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute javascript code, instead of using `eval`, which can be quite a security risk, you should use built-in module [`vm`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html)

```
const vm = require('vm');

const sandbox = { x: 2 }; // pass variables or some context if you want
vm.createContext(sandbox); // Contextify the sandbox.

const code = buffer.toString(); // your buffer
vm.runInContext(code, sandbox);
```

Comment: Thanks I would never come up with this! The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) states that this gives no security mechanism, so why consider using `vm` instead of `eval()`?

Comment: Because it does not give you access to node modules. So they won't be able to use `fs` or other modules, allowing them to read/write or wipe your disk. It has some settings to prevent infinite loops, and it runs in another context that doesn't have access to your variables.